# How to request http in Airtable automation?

Tags: javascript, rest, airtable

I am making a new table in [airtable](https://airtable.com/). 
For calculation total value, I am using automation.
In here, I need to use daily rate of EUR. So, I'd like to use api for it.
How can I call restapi in airtable automation?

Comment: Where are you stuck? You don't know how to fetch an API? You don't know how to fetch a specific airtable API? You don't know what to do with the data after you fetch it?

Comment: for example, if there is https://example.com/api, how can I call this api on airtable automation?

Comment: I would probably start with fetch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch